# Issue with nodejs module 'node-record-lpcm16': Unable to pause or resume recording

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs module **node-record-lpcm16** for recording my audio and converting it to a file, as mentioned in the module's usage page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16). Also, I am using **windows 10**.

However, I get an error while trying to pause the recording at this place:

```
// Pause recording after one second
setTimeout(() => {
        recording.pause() // error occurs here
    }, 1000)
```

The error which I get is as follows:

```
internal/util.js:251
  throw new ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL(signal);
  ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: SIGSTOP
    at convertToValidSignal (internal/util.js:251:9)
    at ChildProcess.kill (internal/child_process.js:476:5)
    at Recording.pause (C:\myproj\node_modules\node-record-lpcm16\index.js:81:18)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\myproj\index.js:113:19)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL'
}
```

On digging further, I found that the error occurs while trying to kill the child process with signal **SIGSTOP** as in the code below in the **index.js** file of the module:

```
pause () {
    assert(this.process, 'Recording not yet started')

    this.process.kill('SIGSTOP') // error occurs here
    this._stream.pause()
    debug('Paused recording')
  }
```

I think that the system is not able to recognize the signal **SIGSTOP** for killing the process.

Similar issue happens on resuming the recording. In that case, the signal not recognized is **SIGCONT**.

Can someone please help in resolving this issue so that I can pause and resume the recording?

Full code is as follows:

```
const recorder = require('node-record-lpcm16')
const fs = require('fs')
 
const file = fs.createWriteStream('test.wav', { encoding: 'binary' })
 
const recording = recorder.record()
recording.stream().pipe(file)
 
// Pause recording after one second
setTimeout(() => {
  recording.pause()
}, 1000)
 
// Resume another second later
setTimeout(() => {
  recording.resume()
}, 2000)
 
// Stop recording after three seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  recording.stop()
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by changing `this.process.kill` to `this.process.emit` in the pause() and resume() functions, which are in the node-record-lpcm16\index.js file.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks Frank

Answer (score -1):

You need to install SoX and it must be available in your $PATH.

To install it in windows download the binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/latest/download)

Comment: I have already installed sox version 14.4.1 (since I was facing some issues with 14.4.2) and made it available in $PATH. The normal recording functionality works. The problem is with pausing and/or resuming the recording. I get unknown signal errors as mentioned in description.